# Magento 1.9x Completely Disable/Remove Minicart

Tags: magento-1.9, minicart

Magento 1.9 using rwd theme, when you click on the cart icon on any page, a [minicart](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-mini.html) will flyout showing what's in your cart. The actual shopping cart page will only be accessible after clicking on the bottom link of the minicart to show cart.

How do you completely disable the minicart?
Instead, I want the cart icon to take you directly to the shopping cart page.

Already set **Display Shopping Cart Sidebar** > **No**, no difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to remove minicart block `minicart_head` from checkout layout file (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/checkout.xml). Don't modify core code of course, copy checkout.xml to local theme directory first.